# How to apply glow effect on image android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to apply these types of glow effects on image view https://codepen.io/aundrekerr/pen/GtLul

In my app, I want to apply on https://prnt.sc/nu06gt
Is there a way to make the header on the Home listing kind of animate subtly like a gloss over w/ the pattern we have?  Like, have it on the angle of the lines.

```
  I have tried with facebook shimmer effect but it's not look like what I want
   https://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android

Comment: okay, Let me look.

Answer (score 1):

first create a shape with some whit/grey gradient as a shine drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <gradient
            android:angle="135"
            android:centerColor="#AAffffff"
            android:endColor="#00ffffff"
            android:startColor="#00ffffff"
            android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

and then you will add this `drawable` to your layout as overlay of you menu icon

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shine"
        android:layout_width="icon_width"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
        android:layout_height="icon_height"
        android:src="@drawable/shine_effect" />
```

**Note** that the width and height of the shine `ImageView` should had the same `width` and `height` as you menu icon .

and then in your logic side create an animation

```
    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, img.getWidth()+shine.getWidth(),0, 0); //img is menu icon , shine is gradient drawable 
    animation.setDuration(550);
    animation.setFillAfter(false);
    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    shine.startAnimation(animation);
```

**edit**

i have updated the gradient example to make it fit your requirement and now to achieve the rest of the requirement you should add 2 another animation.

animation one with a duration of 225 that start with the main animation that increase size and alpha value (fade out effect) .

animation two with a duration of 225 that start with the end of animation one that decrease the size and alpha value (fade in effect)

hope you understand my example

Comment: Have you seen my image.I want to apply only that design.and that way only.

Comment: please check this result : https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*IsRT9dTBMW5d8P0rj5zcMg.gif

Comment: I'm not able to seen result.Link 404 not found

Comment: Please copy all the link til the gif

Comment: ok let me try.but I want to start left corner and increase size accordingly.

Comment: Try to implement this example and as soon as it works we gonna try to achieve your criteria

Comment: Hi,I have done like in this example but how to fit in my requirement ?

Comment: i have updated the gradient example. I'm not able to see updated code.It's look same like yesterday.Where is gradient example ?

Comment: yeah i updated the code , i add angle and linear type

Comment: but it's like straight line.I make to rotate whole drawable

Comment: No it should be inclined that why i put angle , i got an inclined drawable when i tested it